# Where can I find the syntax list in Wolfram Alpha for Math and Science Subjects?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

Google is able to do simple to medium mathematical calculations but Wolfram Alpha is like Mathematica online. What I would like to do is test the limits, such as what syntax is defined and what is not.

From the [examples](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/) they have given, let's pick the Engineering Section. It is lacking in my opinion, based on the mathematical functions like solving ordinary differential equations, simple addition and so forth. I cannot understand why they do not have more Engineering examples.

Case [Carbon Steel](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=carbon+steel)

This returns physical, mechanical and thermal properties (inclusive of thermal conductivity).

But where can I find the extended syntax to know what I can add or not add?

For example I only got this by trial and error: [NPS 1 inch steel 25ft](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NPS+1+inch+steel+25ft).

I know this engine is capable of doing more than I am seeing. I just want to know where is the *push more* button/section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Wolfram Alpha is ***not*** like Mathematica and lacks a formal syntax. Trial and error ***is*** the method you use to interact with it. This shortcoming is its most serious flaw and the source of much criticism. (By the way, there is often a "more" link at the upper right of result "pods".)